# WPF Listview binding to ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have the following listview, but it doesn't show the actual records, but only the namespace of the object.  I wondered if I need to create the columns in XAML for it to show the records and then bind it to some properties of an object or what is wrong with this?

```
<ListView
            Name="ListCustomers"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfCustomers}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            MinHeight="100"

            ></ListView>
```

`ListOfCustomers` is an `ObservableCollection<Customer>` type.  The actual customers do get loaded into the ObservableCollection, but they are not displayed.  What is missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to select the columns to display as well:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCustomers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer}"
          ....>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="First Name"
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  />
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Last Name"  
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Email Address"
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
      ....
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try

```
<ListView
.
.
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerDataTemplate}"
.
.
/>
```

where CustomerDataTemplate is a DataTemplate for Customer class...

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have not set the `DataContext` property of the ListView with the instance that exposes the `ListOfCustomers` property (which returns the list of items to be displayed) ?

Comment: I have set the datacontext of the window to the class that contains the property, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @Tony - yes should be. It should bubble up to find the data context. Seems that you have it solved from the acc answer. What was the problem?

Comment: Problem was that I had no columns created in my listview that are bound to my Customer class.